# ¿Como poder graficar esta consulta con ChartJS?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, chart.js

Un poco del contexto: tomo los cursos y sus respectivos estudiantes, realizo una vista contando los temas que existen para ese curso, el estudiante ve los temas y cuento también cuantos ha visto, luego calculo ese promedio, toma los datos correctos, pero quisiera evitar la repetición de la primer columna, o sea agrupar sin que se tenga que repetir el nombre del curso:

```
cursos  usuario_id     nombre          ap_p   total_temas   vistos  porcen  
Excel       2        Estudiante         A_P        2          2     100.0000
Excel       3        Estudiante No. 2   AP         2          0     0.0000
Test        3        Estudiante No. 2   AP         7          7     100.0000
Test        5        Estudiante No. 3   XV         7          2     28.5714
Test        2        Estudiante         A_P        7          3     42.8571
Word        3        Estudiante No. 2   AP         1          0     0.0000
Word        7        Estudiante No. 5   ES         1          0     0.0000
```

O si hay documentación, ejemplos, cualquier cosa me serviría de mucha ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Sigue este ejemplo:
Primero define tus columnas  y datos en Json format.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Dataset #1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};

var option = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
};

Chart.Bar('chart_0', {
  options: option,
  data: data
});
```

```css
body {  
  background: #1D1F20;
  padding: 16px;
}

.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="chart_0"></canvas>
</div>
```

saludos.

Comment: Lo he hecho, reemplacé los valores de los meses por los cursos de mi consulta, pero no se agrupan, me repite el nombre del curso, habrá alguna manera de agruparlos?